# application stops running and exit when press the button in android studio

Tags: android

```
 cancelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCncl);

    cancelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            //txtViewOff.setText("");
            txtViewOn.setText("Countdown Timer Canceled");


            //Timer to set visible text view
            Timer t = new Timer(false);
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            txtViewOn.setText("");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 3000);
        }

    });
```

when i click on the button related to this code the app get crashes..i made this to cancel the timer

Comment: You'll need to post the crash log to begin the troubleshooting process. Use the logcat window at the bottom of Android Studio to find the log. Once you get that, post it here and the Stackoverflow community can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clear idea about this without a crash log. But according to this code most probably it may be a null pointer exception. try below thing by adding a null check before call countdowntimer

```
 if(countDownTimer != null){
    countDownTimer.cancel();
 }
```